# Creating FB tab that links to other FB pages

Tags: facebook, tabs

I am trying to connect all the various Facebook presences for Burlington College under our tabs so people can easily get to all the FB pages for the college from one place.

The Create a Tab function/app will not allow me to link to a Facebook URL.  Surely there must be some way to connect all our pages?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this, is to create a page tab application, and serve a page that has links to all the other Facebook pages.

You would need to build the HTML for that page and then point the tab URL to that page on a secure server.